# Setting and resetting the countdown in every page Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to implement a count down timer, so once I navigate to each screen the timer should reset.

So for each every minute the timer should automatically initialize and starts the count down from 10 to 0.

If user interupts in the middle of count down it should be in the same page, else it should navigate to home page.

This is what I have tried. My timer is calling only once and how do I know that the page has been changed and reset the timer to calulate from 1 minute.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Function to update counters on all elements with class counter
  var doUpdate = function() {
    $('.countdown').each(function() {
      var count = parseInt($(this).html());
      if (count !== 0) {
        $(this).html(count - 1);
      }
    });
  };

  // Schedule the update to happen once every second
  setInterval(doUpdate, 1000);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="countdown">10</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have reached `0` on your countdown you could clear your current intervals using `clearInterval()` and restart the whole process after a minute. You could have another setInterval() which does this every minute.

Here is a fiddle which resets counters every 12 seconds: http://jsfiddle.net/uo7jLf4b/1/